# Создание представлений View в MS SQL. Объединить две похожие таблицы

Tags: sql

Есть база данных MS SQL и в ней две таблицы, import и export, таблицы совпадают на 95%.

Обе таблицы содержат колонку [Дата], [Цена], [Количество], [Вес], [Тип].
В типе содержится тип, то есть импорт или экспорт (у таблицы импорт - соответственно импорт, у таблицы экспорта - экспорт).
Есть так же и уникальные столбцы, у import - [Покупатель], у export - [Продавец]

Мне необходимо объединить данные две таблицы сохранив все уникальные поля, то есть во View модели должен быть и продавец и покупатель, но если это import, то продавец будет null (или просто пустое поле). Возможно ли это реализовать?

Comment: *то есть во View модели должен быть и продавец и покупатель,* Но записей должно остаться две? тогда UNION ALL. Или их надо собрать в одну? тогда FULL JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так и выбирайте ровным счетом то что написали:

```
SELECT ...
    , NULL AS [покупатель]
    , [продавец]
FROM ....
UNION ALL
SELECT ....
    , [покупатель]
    , NULL AS [подавец]
FROM ...
```

Comment: Лучше UNION ALL, чтоб не тратить время на поиск одинаковых строк, которых точно не будет

Comment: @ГерманБорисов ага, поправил.

Comment: Да, извините. Вероятно я допустил ошибку в написании своего SQL запроса, так как писал '''NULL AS [подавец]''', но получал ошибку. Ваш ответ в целом решил мои проблемы :)